# wxFileDialog filename textbox appears as clipped

Tags: textbox, filenames, wxwidgets, openfiledialog, filedialog

I display an Open File dialog using the following code:

```
wxFileDialog fileDialog(
    this,
    wxEmptyString,
    "E:\\Testfiles",
    "SOME_TEST_FILE_WITH_LONG_NAME.txt",
    "TXT files (*.txt)|*.txt",
    wxFD_OPEN | wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wxFD_CHANGE_DIR);
if (fileDialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
{
    // do something with the file
}
```

Notice that I set the default filename to a long string (about 10 or more characters).
When the file dialog is displayed, the filename **looks** clipped.

[image: file chooser dialog with clipped filename]

But on inspection, it's not really clipped.
More like the starting point of the text is placed too much to the left.
When you place the cursor on the textbox, and scroll to the left, you get the complete filename.

[image: file chooser dialog with scrolled filename]

Also, when you switch to a different window then return to the file dialog, it corrects itself and displays the complete filename.

This isn't really affecting the functionality of the file dialog.
This is more of an aesthetic issue.

But if there's a reason for this behavior or if there's a solution, I would like to know.

Thanks!

I'm using:

- wxWidgets 3.1.0
- Windows 10 Home 64-bit

---

**UPDATE (2017/03/20)**:

I opened a ticket at wxTrac for this bug.
You can check it here: 
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17824.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary workaround (while an [official resolution from wxWidgets](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17824) is not yet available), calling `CenterOnParent()` after constructing the file dialog properly "scrolls" the filename so that it won't appear as "clipped".

```
wxFileDialog fileDialog(
    this,
    wxEmptyString,
    "E:\\Testfiles",
    "SOME_TEST_FILE_WITH_LONG_NAME.txt",
    "TXT files (*.txt)|*.txt",
    wxFD_OPEN | wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST | wxFD_CHANGE_DIR);

// fixes the clipped filename
fileDialog.CenterOnParent();

if (fileDialog.ShowModal() == wxID_OK)
{
    // do something with the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in wxWidgets, please try to reproduce it in the [dialogs sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.0/samples/dialogs/dialogs.cpp) by making minimal changes to the `wxFileDialog` call which is already present there and open a ticket on [wxTrac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket) with the patch allowing to see the problem, so that someone could debug it.

Comment: As suggested, I was able to reproduce the bug using the **minimal** sample code then I submitted a ticket(link to-follow) to wxTrac. I'll update this post with the link after/if the ticket gets approved. Thanks.